# deployed react app with express to github but it shows : 404 There isn't a GitHub Pages site here, when deployed to heroku 404 not found nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, heroku, backend, github-pages

After i deployed my react app which also uses express.js i keep getting 404:There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

similarly i have tried to deploy it to heroku but it shows me 404: not found nginx while all of this were working before i made some backend to my app.

i have searched the whole internet and didn't find my answer.

Please any one with an idea of how to fix it? Down below is my repo which contains all the code.
https://github.com/AbdullahGumi/crwn-clothing

Comment: React apps typically require some build process to be deployed. For instance, on Heroku you can specify a Buildpack on the settings page. For React you can use https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack. Have you tried something like that?

Comment: yes i have done that but still it is not working